# Smoothing curved model

Tags: modeling, vertices

I got a model from a colleague, who exported it from adobe. Now the surface is not really smooth on some places inspecting it from near.

I already added more vertices, which did smooth out some edges, but what I want is that it is smooth like the first 2 images. Last 2 images is the one i want to smooth out. How would you achieve that?

[image: model]

[image]

[image][image]

[3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj8mp.jpg

Comment: Hello you could try a Ctrl V > Smooth Vertices but maybe share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I already did smooth vertices on that images I uploaded. What's the best way to share?

Comment: use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions)

Comment: I just noticed that the blend file is nearly 400mb...

Comment: Only share this part of your object, if it is still too heavy use another platform, like workupload for example

Comment: I tried to export just the part, but it seems that the part is the heavy one, so here the file: https://workupload.com/file/LvkjARJEQMg

Comment: The topology seems pretty complicated and hard to clean, maybe you should redo from scratch

Comment: ok thx for taking your time.